# Is this an acceptable way to determine if an object is an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, types

I have often used this code to determine if an array is really an array...

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(array) == '[object Array]'
```

I recently started changing my callback tests from `typeof callback == 'function'` to `callback instanceof Function`, because I read that Safari and Chrome will tell you a regex literal is a function using the former (and it did when I tested it).

Now, I decided to check this code to see if I can replace the verbose code above...

```
array instanceof Array
```

It worked.

[Comparison of both on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/dQA2m/).

So, is there any issues with the latter method? I assumed there may be because the first code example came up much more often in Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two problems with using `instanceof` for an array are:

- Returns `false` when the array is from another window or frame
- Breaks if the `Array` constructor has been overwritten

The following is an article by kangax where I first saw your first technique (also used in jQuery): http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/

Answer (score 3):

In ES5 you can call:

```
Array.isArray(obj);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

See also [their note](https://developer.mozilla.org/web-tech/2010/07/26/determining-with-absolute-accuracy-whether-or-not-a-javascript-object-is-an-array/) where they say that a pure Javascript implementation cannot be a guaranteed 100% emulation of the native code version.

Comment: From a quick test on the latest Chrome, I can write `Array.isArray = function(){return false;}`. Does that really solve the issue? Or should that not be possible? (I'm not big on the new JavaScript, so it's very possible I'm missing some basic fact)

Comment: interesting - I would have expected them to make that function immutable

Answer (score 2):

If it's any help, this is how it's done in [`jQuery.isArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isArray/):

```
isArray: Array.isArray || function( obj ) {
    return jQuery.type(obj) === "array";
}

type: function( obj ) {
    return obj == null ?
             String( obj ) :
             class2type[ toString.call(obj) ] || "object";
}
```

toString:

```
toString = Object.prototype.toString
```

`class2type` is an associative array, which is initialized as:

```
jQuery.each("Boolean Number String Function Array Date RegExp Object".split(" "),
             function(i, name) {
                 class2type[ "[object " + name + "]" ] = name.toLowerCase();
             });
```

If that is any indication, jQuery is using your first method, and tests it extensively.

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue if someone overwrites your global Array variable. Quite unlikely, but if you want a really failsafe method, stick to #1.

[Demonstration on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N4ZpV/).

Comment: Thanks, but won't the same happen if [I overwrite `Object`](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/dQA2m/1/)?

Comment: Can't you just as easily override `Object.toString`? - `Object.prototype.toString = function(){return ":-)";}` - Demo: http://jsbin.com/awixe4 . I suspect JavaScript is crazy.

Comment: there is **no** failsafe method

Comment: @alex if your overwrite `Object` every JS developer will find you and get you.

Comment: @Raynos I was just using it as an example.

Comment: @alex still it should never happen just like `window.undefined = true` or `window.$ = window.jQuery = function() { return null; }`

Answer (score 0):

there is no issues with method

```
array instanceof Array
```

you can use function

```
function is_array( mixed_var ) {    // Finds whether a variable is an array
    return ( mixed_var instanceof Array );
}
```

Comment: If you review the very interesting link in Alnitak's answer, you'll see it doesn't work in all cases, like when `mixed_var` comes from another window, a scenario referred to as "Pfui".

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is the way Ext does it:

```
function isArray (obj) {
    return obj != null && typeof obj == 'object' && 'splice' in obj && 'join' in obj;
}
```

This relies on checking for the existance of splice and join. Two functions that should only be in an array. Of course this would fail if you passed an object that had functions called splice and join (and wasn't an array), but then you probably shouldn't be doing that in the first place.