# How can I tell if it is an object or an array?

Tags: javascript, typeof

I want to know the type of the variable put in the function. So, I used `typeof` and like this:

```
randomFunctionName: function(obj){
    switch(typeof obj){
        case "object":
           //Something
        case "text":
            //Something else
    }
}
```

But the problem is, I can't tell if `obj` is an array or an object, since

```
typeof [] === "object"  //true
typeof {} === "object"  //true
```

So, how I can I separate them? Is there any difference between them?

Comment: I think this is a common advanced topic, such as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587061/how-to-determine-if-object-is-in-array

Comment: Another example is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844981/distinguish-between-array-and-hash-in-javascript-with-typeof

Comment: Or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336090/is-this-an-acceptable-way-to-determine-if-an-object-is-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: How can you find those links? I searched for a few times and what I found is `nothing` related.

Comment: Search terms were `determine object or array`

Comment: Well, looks like I am not so good at searching stuffs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An array is an object.  You can test if an object is an array as follows:

```
Object.prototype.toString.apply(value) === '[object Array]';
```

You can wrap this up into a function as follows:

```
function isArray(a)
{
    return Object.prototype.toString.apply(a) === '[object Array]';
}
```

Comment: Is `[object Array]` the same in every browser?

Comment: Yes, this will work for any browser that is ECMAScript compliant, which should be all browsers.

Answer (score 4):

check the constructor:

```
[].constructor == Array  //true
{}.constructor == Object  //true
```

Comment: `{}.constructor` --> `SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

Comment: I see the image but I don't get the error in chrome(the image looks like chrome)

Comment: I am using Chrome 20.0.1115.1  Do you think it is a bug of Chrome or did I do something wrong?

Comment: The latest version I can get (winXP) is 18.0.1025.162 m and i don't get any  error. chrome19 is BETA and chrome20 is dev, so I don't have do care about them because they don't have to be stable.

Comment: I am actually using the dev channel, but I don't think that will affect JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

Since ECMAScript 5 you can use the native method:

```
Array.isArray( maybeArray );
```

If compatibility is of concern you can use [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#isArray) or [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isArray/):

```
_.isArray( maybeArray ); // will use the native method if available
$.isArray( maybeArray );
```

This kind of utility is also present in AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple. Try something like

```
var to = {}.toString;
alert(to.call([])); //[object Array]
alert(to.call({})); //[object Object]
```